# Eigen phred score interpretation

Tags: variation, dbnsfp

I need help. I am not able to find any reference for Eigen_phred_coding prediction tools score from [dbNSFP](http://database.liulab.science/dbNSFP).

I know that it may be scaled in a similar manner to CADD_phred - ranking raw values from highest to smallest; get rank of that value in the queue; phred scale that value with the same formula as sequencing quality score.

But I couldn't find the phred scaling of Eigen values directly, not to mention its suggested cutoff (same as CADD_phred > 15 or different?).

**How are the Eigen scores transformed into Eigen_phred?**

**Is it in same manner as Cadd_phred?**

**If so, can same cutoff be used in both cases?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for that reference. I don't know why, but I always thought that CADD_phred is phred scaled value of ratio rank of value in sorted queue over the total number of used SNV. At least in read me I found out that everything phred is  ratio of rank of the variat over total number of scores in database. Still I am not sure with the cutoff of 15. Anyway I am going to try that.